# react build strange behaviour while serving with apache

Tags: reactjs

I an unable to serve react app using apache proxy pass. I have configure proxy pass

```
ProxyPass /frontend/ http://localhost:5002/
 ProxyPassReverse /frontend/ http://localhost:5002/
```

and created the react build in frontend folder but whenever i am trying to reach url i can only see the blank white page, evenafter all resources are successfully loaded.
[image: picture reference].Also my build is working fine on my local machine.
All the paths in my index.html for static contents are correct according to deployment machine. please help me out in this!

Comment: What is running on `http://localhost:5002/`? `npm run build` only produces production static files in the `build` folder. It does not any development server

Comment: @MaartenDev , I tried serving the build with npm serve and python createHTTPServer, both are working fine on local but not on the machine.

Comment: You should not use a http server for production, you have to serve the static files using nginx or apache